# VBA store path including Environ("username") in a text file

Tags: vba, ms-word, filepath

I am trying to create a text file that stores a folder path. This text file is then referenced via a vba sub. The path I want to use is something like:

```
"C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
```

This works fine in the sub but I've tried all kinds of variations in the text file but none of them get recognised and trigger error 52 - bad file.

Is there a way to make this work? I'm trying to allow people to set a different file path without needing to modify the code.

Comment: It's not clear what context you're using this if not "in the sub". There's nothing wrong with what you posted, but it's not even a single line of code.

Comment: Are you using that exact string stored in a text file?  I'm guessing that either you're trying to get the text file to translate `Environ("username")` which it can't do, or you're reading the whole text string back into Word in which case `Environ` would be part of the text string and not translated by VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to provide a path to the folder where user templates are stored then you could try

`ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path`

as an alternative (returns the path to the folder where the current template is stored for the user).

Otherwise store the path template as something like

```
"C:\Users\###UserName###\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
```

Which gives you a single string to retrieve.  Then you can use the VBA Replace function to change the ###UserName### to the value of Environ("UserName)"

```
my_user_path = replace(my_path_template, Environ$("UserName"))
```

You might also want to explore using either a CustomDocumentProperty, or a Variables, to store your path template as this keeps the path template string as part of the Document or Template and not in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, the function idea is going to work best for me. Cheers, Mark